# Why my responsive menu, is not showing on width resize/change?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The nav list items are not showing up once the width change or the page is resized.

There's a Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/rnichael/pen/bebjEK) and the code is below

```
    <nav class="isotope-filters nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="info">Infomation</li>
            <li>Filter:</li>
            <li><a class="selected" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
            <li><a data-filter=".ads">One</a></li>
            <li><a data-filter=".des">Two</a></li>
            <li><a data-filter=".art">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://mrthomason.tumblr.com">Four</a>
            </li>
            <li class="filter">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">Filter</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font: bold 16px/21px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}



nav {
    float: right;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.info:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    cursor: pointer
}



a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer
}

li:nth-child(1) {
    padding-right: 0;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
    color: darkgray;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

nav.isotope-filters ul li a:active,
nav.isotope-filters ul li a.selected {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.filter {display: none;}


@media screen and (max-width:680px) {

   .nav ul li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .nav ul li.filter {display: inline-block; padding-left: 15px;}    
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  .nav ul.responsive {position: relative;}
  .nav ul.responsive li.filter {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav ul.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
   .nav ul.responsive li  {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Then I'm using the below script:

```
function myFunction() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
    }
```

The console log is showing no errors.

So, it hides the list items, shows 'filter' but **doesn't display the hidden list items** like it should do.

Comment: You are adding the `responsive` class to the `nav` but your css expects it to be applied to the `ul`

Comment: @Turnip not quite sure what you mean. Am I not taking my parent `.nav`.and adding `.responsive` when it hit my breakpoint?

Comment: Yes. But your css is looking for a `ul` with a class of `responsive`. Here:  `.nav ul.responsive li { ... }`. You either need to add the class to the `ul` rather than the `nav` or change your css

Comment: You're correct. Got the css jumbled up. Do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Add this `id` to your `nav` - `id="respnav"` - then change your JavaScript code:

```
 function myFunction() {
    var d = document.getElementById("respnav");
    d.className += "responsive";
}
```

This get the `nav` element and add the class `responsive` to it. It's working ok here: [See the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRbBgj)

And an image of a small viewport
[image]

Comment: this loses the toggle and dropdown.